# How to organize Ada project in directories?

Tags: ada

How can I load two packages with the same name but located in seperate folders?

Example:

```
/src/alpha/foopackage.ads
/src/beta/foopackage.ads
```

I then would like to use foopackages using:

```
with alpha.foopackage; 
with beta.foopackage;
```

Also, if you have any other tips about organizing projects in Ada please write. There is not much info about project organization in Ada on the net.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've already solved the problem!

src/alpha/foopackage.ads contains:

```
package alpha.foopackage is

   ...

end alpha.foopackage;
```

while src/beta/foopackage.ads contains:

```
package beta.foopackage is

   ...

end beta.foopackage;
```

Now you *will* run into a temporary problem if you're using GNAT and its default naming convention. This naming convention requires that the files be named alpha-foopackage.ads and beta-foopackage.ads, respectively.

If you insist on using foopackage.ads as the filenames, this convention can be worked around. With GNAT, see [Handling Arbitrary File Naming Conventions with gnatname](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Handling-Arbitrary-File-Naming-Conventions-with-gnatname.html), [Using Other File Names](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Using-Other-File-Names.html#Using-Other-File-Names), or [Alternative File Naming Schemes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Alternative-File-Naming-Schemes.html#Alternative-File-Naming-Schemes).

Answer (score 4):

This is almost a duplicate of the question which led to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12587981/40851).

However, there's another issue to do with naming, which is that GNAT (I think you are using GNAT?) has a [default file naming convention](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn_unw/File-Naming-Rules.html) (there are ways of overriding this convention, but you'd need a Good Reason to bother).

So your source files, whatever directory you choose to put them in, should be named `alpha-foopackage.ads` and `beta-foopackage.ads` respectively.